# Why are Client projects referenced in Server Projects in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-boilerplate

I was looking at a few recommended blazor kits type projects and I couldn't help but notice that all server-side projects I've seen online happen to have the client project added as a reference to the server project... For example, in https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate, we have this:

[image: Reference]

This reference causes this where I'm triggered:

[image: Invalid startup option]

Is there something I'm missing here? I have followed numerous tutorials but no one has explicitly highlighted this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d3400f7cb23d83ae93b536a5fc9f46fc2274ce68/src/Components/Blazor/Server/src/Builder/BlazorHostingApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs) it is clear that this is used to serve up the Client App and all the assemblies it uses.

You can find the 2 relevant lines in the server Startup class:

```cs
app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();
...
  endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
```

in both cases the `Client.Startup` class is used to find the assembly and from there on some Reflection is used to determine which (static) files to serve.

You can remove the project reference and pass a `clientAssemblyFilePath` instead of `<Client.Startup>` to both methods. That may require some tweaks to the build targets. Consider it a convenience feature.